# Controller method not redirecting properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

I currently Have a controller method that increments 1 on a attribute and then it should redirect to a particular page with that user found. But for a reason I can't figure out it keeps rendering the else statement and the end of the method. I'll post my code then clear things up once you see it.

CONTROLLER:

```
  def search
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
  end

  def visit
    @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by_phone_number(params[:phone_number])
    if @subscriber
      @subscriber.visit ||= 0
      @subscriber.visit += 1
      @subscriber.save
      flash[:notice] = "Thank You #{@subscriber.first_name}. You have #{@subscriber.days_till_expired} until renewal"
      redirect_to subscribers_visit_path(:subscriber)
    else
      render "search"
    end
  end
```

VIEW:

```
<h1>Hello Subscriber</h1>

<% if @subscriber %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= image_tag avatar_url(@subscriber) %></td>
    <td><%= @subscriber.first_name %></td>
  </tr>
<% else %>
  <tr><td>No subscriber found!</td></tr>
<% end %>
```

For whatever reason it keeps rendering the "search" in the else part of the method and not the subscriber_visit_path but it does the `+= 1` part just fine. So, basically it's finding the subscriber but after it increments it seems to make the subscriber go nil? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: How do you know it's "done the `+= 1` part"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment from Mr Bass - do you have tests to make sure the process is working?

Especially the `if @subscriber`.

I might try using the built in `exists?` in your if statement, this guarantees a true or false outcome.

Comment: That's superfluous code; `if @subscriber` would do exactly the same thing in this case.

Comment: Well, i'm only a mildly advanced beginner, but when I go into my rails console and look for a specific record by id, and the id doesn't exist, it does not return 'nil' - it returns a big old ActiveRecord:RecordNotFound error.  I don't know that rails treats errors as nil does it?

Comment: I can't verify what you've said as I don't have Rails to hand right now, but you need to put the `byebug` gem in the `:development, :test` group of your Gemfile and run `bundle`. Then put `byebug` on the line after `@subscriber = Subscriber.find_by... etc` line. Then fire up your rails server and go to your visit page. When everything pauses, go back to your command line and you'll see that byebug has halted everything and you can play with the code. Type `@subscriber` and see what that returns.